# vim how to configure backspace and delete key's both as normal

Tags: bash, vim, key-mapping

How to configure following keys in `vim`?

- <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key to delete a character backwards.
- <kbd>Delete</kbd> key to delete a character forwards.

After reading some posts, I got to know that only one of those can be used to delete a character. But I guess the above behavior would be achievable.

#### Current scenario

1. `Backspace` working as said above.
2. `Delete` key is however acting weird. On pressing it, the character under the cursor get's replaced by `~`, and later 5-6 keystrokes changes it to aplahabet and also change the case. `Vim` comes back to normal mode after that, leaving messed-up text.

#### Details

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.0 (2006 May 7, compiled Jun 12 2009 07:08:36)
```

If the above is not configurable, Please let me know, How I can at-least map <kbd>Delete</kbd> key to nothing, so that above weird behavior doesn't take place ?

Comment: What terminal are you using? Is the `TERM` environment variable set correctly?

Comment: In a terminal, what do you see when you type `Ctrl-V` `Del`?  Compare the output of `:echo &term` in Vim and `echo $TERM` in your shell - they should be the same.  As mentioned above, make sure the `$TERM` value is correct, and then make sure the Vim `term` value matches.

Answer (score 3):

In the `tcsh` shell, add this line in your `~/.cshrc` file:

```
stty erase '^?'
```

Answer (score 1):

I do that with help of the `stty` command, just add this line to your .bashrc file:

```
stty erase ^?
```

you do that by typing `stty erase` and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> and finally press the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key.

Hope that fixes the problem.

Comment: The weird behavior is still present.

Answer (score 0):

All the vim settings have to be done in a file called .vimrc located in $HOME. It is initially empty. I have vim 7.3 and both the keys are working fine. I suggest you to go through this link

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Backspace_and_delete_problems#Delete_key_problems